# get logged in user info in CodeIgniter (HMVC & Ion Auth)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get Logged in user details in CodeIgniter (HMVC & Ion Auth)

```
$data['user'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

When i try to display i am getting error

```
Undefined variable: user
```

I am not sure how to get loggin in user id or email. I need id or email. Please help

Comment: if $this->ion_auth->logged_in() is working in this module

Comment: Are you sure the error you get refers to this line above? It's for some line in the view file as I understand

Comment: "When i try to display i am getting error" - where is your display code?

Comment: Hello, Thank you i  don't know How it is showing data now :) Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If your are trying to display it in view,

Are you passing the $data variable to the view ?

```
$data['user']=$this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$this->load->view("filename",$data);
```

If you are trying to access it with the controller you can access the variable like

```
$data['user']=$this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$username=$data['user']->username;
```

Please specify where you are initializing it and where you are accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

I will say one example. Follow this example may be it will help you.

Suppose you have a login form with Email and Password fields. When you submitted that form it will check whether you submitted properly with validation errors and everything. If everything 
is okay. It will check whether it is valid email and password match from database. If that also true than those email and username will save to session data in model of MVC design pattern. Once when you succeeded you just need to retrieve user information from that session data in controller and you need pass that data in an array to the next page after login.

```
$logged_in = $this->session->userdata("logged_in_user");
```