# Pass user data (from Ion Auth) to view on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller I check if an user is logged in, and if its true I tried to pass the data to the view

```
$user= $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$this->load->view('niceview',$user);
```

And use it that data on the view:

```
echo 'Hi' . $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name.'!';
```

But I Get the following error:

```
Message: Undefined variable: user
```

Looking for how to pass the data I pass by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929113/get-logged-in-user-info-in-codeigniter-hmvc-ion-auth), but the question isn't clear, and the answer state that I could use:

```
$data['user']=$this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$this->load->view("filename",$data);
```

In that case, I tried to get the user back with:

```
$user=$data['user'];
```

But I got the same undefined error

```
Message: Undefined variable: data
```

So, How can I pass the data from the user with Ion Auth to a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my error.
When you pass the data to a view you don't call the variable data again, just what it's inside (you pass an array and on the view you need to work with the elements from the array).
So, I pass the user on the controller

```
$data['user']=$this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$this->load->view("filename",$data);
```

And on the view, I don't need to get the variable data, just the data inside it (that is the variable $user)... so I just remove this line from the view

```
$user=$data['user']; //I remove this line
```

And I could use the user with, for example, this

```
echo 'Hi' . $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name.'!';
```